# Eclipse scout hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-scout

I used Eclipse Scout and i followed the instructions in the tutorial to create the sample application. It looks great and it was very easy to build an application with it.

I would like to ask if anyone has used it for a 'real' application and how it worked for him.
Is there a tutorial/example on how i could use Eclipse Scout with Hibernate?

Answer (score 5):

Glad you liked Scout so far! We (BSI, a Swiss software company) use Eclipse Scout successfully since many years for all our products which are a Customer Relationship Management System, for a contact center solution, and for a clinical trial management system. Some of these applications are used by thousands of users other just by a couple of dozens.

Regarding Scout and Hibernate, one of us is building a sample application right now to demo Scout, JPA and Hibernate. The result will be posted on our [Scout wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout) in the near future so we can properly answer your question in our [forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/354498/)

Comment: @matthias - Did this info get added to the wiki?  All I could find was this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/3.8/ScoutAndHibernate - the page is empty and says "work in progress"

Answer (score 0):

Now that Eclipse Scout has moved from OSGI to became J2EE oriented and maven based framework, I suppose that using Hibernate and other frameworks is easy.

EDIT :
There is an exemple of scout + spring boot + spring data integration :
https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/ScoutBoot-Tasks